# Matplotlib Figure Size Option Splitting the plots

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a reference file (A_B_0) and 5 other associated files (A_B_1, A_B_2....A_B_5) in the same plot. My X-axis will be same but I will have variations in Y-coordinates. My issue is when I am trying to use the plt.figure(figsize=()) option, it is plotting all of them as individual plots. So, instead of getting 1 plot, I am getting 5 individual plots with (A_B_0 and A_B_1), (A_B_0 and A_B_2).....(A_B_0 and A_B_5). Any help on fixing this issue would be really appreciated.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib notebook
    filelist=[]
    for i in range (1,6):
        filelist.append("/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_B_%s.txt" %i)
    for fname in Filelist:
        data= pd.read_table(fname, dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
        data1= pd.read_table('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_B_0.txt', dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
        x=np.arange(1,100, 1)
        y=data[:,2]
        y1=data1[:,2]
        plt.plot(x,y)
        plt.plot(x,y1)
        plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
        plt.show()
```

Comment: First, you need to call `plt.figure()' only once just before the second loop. Second, you need to call `plt.show()` only ones just after the second loop. But you call both of them for each data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I'm not sure it will work. I cannot test this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
filelist=["/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_B_%s.txt"%i for i in range (1,6) ]
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
x=np.arange(1,100, 1)
data1= pd.read_table('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_B_0.txt', dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
y1=data1[:,2]
plt.plot(x,y1)
for fname in Filelist:
   data= pd.read_table(fname, dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
   y=data[:,2]
   plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I need the y1 and 5 different y's in the same plot to compare.